# k-path problem - P, NP or NPC?

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, np-complete, np

I need to determine which complexity class this problem belongs to:

> Given a graph $G(V, E)$, two vertices $u$ and $v$ and a natural number $k$, does a path of length $k$ exist between thesee two vertices?

How can I approach this problem to solve it?

Comment: What does it look like if you pick $k = |V|-1$ ... ? (you should also specify if the path must be simple or not)

Comment: What do you think about membership to NP? That might be an easy starting point. This is the other "component" you need if you wish to show NP-completeness.

Comment: Why do you need this? What have you tried?

Comment: You should view this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231841/powers-of-adjacency-matrix-determination-of-connection-in-graph

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/143930/755

Answer (score 1):

If the path has to be simple reduce the HamiltonPath problem to this to show that's NP-complete, otherwise (not necessarily simple paths) take the $k$-th power of the adjacency matrix, whose entry corresponding to $u$ and $v$ not only contains whether there is such a path, but also the number of such paths.

Answer (score 0):

it is a member of NP because you can design certificate for this problem , when the path you want to find is not necessarily simple you can solve it in polynomial time , if it is simple then this problem is NP complete problem .... if you want more then you can try by yourself to search or to make proof of your own ...

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Given a vertex $v$, can you enumerate all vertices for which there is a path of length 1 from $v$? Then all vertices with for which there is a path of length 2 from $v$, etc.? How long does each step take in terms of $|V|$ and $|E|$?