# K-Path-Problem is in $P$ or $NPC$

Tags: graphs, np-complete, np

> Given an undirected graph $G(V, E)$, two vertices $u$ and $v$ and a natural number $k$, does a path of at least length $k$ exists between these two vertices?

How can we solve this problem? I think maybe that it's in $NPC$ with a reduction of HamiltonPath but I'm not sure.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/11680. Also, since the wording is letter-for-letter identical in both questions, I assume this is taken from some textbook; if so, you should properly attribute the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is $\textsf{NP}$-complete. This is more or less the [longest path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem).